# How to print a Visual with pagination in WPF?

Tags: wpf, printing, pagination

I have a ScrollViewer and very "long" content in it. 
I wrote a class that inherits from DocumentPaginator, but I don't understand how do I create a "frame" for every part of this Visual? I mean, how do I "look" at the next page of the control?
I tried this, but with no success:

```
    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        double left = pageNumber * pageSize.Width;
        Point pt = new Point(left, 0);

        visual.RenderTransform = Transform.Identity;
        visual.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-left, 0);

        visual.Measure(pageSize);
        visual.Arrange(new Rect(visual.DesiredSize));

        DocumentPage page = new DocumentPage(visual);
        return page;
    }
```

With this code I get first page as it should be, second page is exactly like first, and all the rest pages are blank.

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentPaginator` is pretty tricky. Here are a few steps that helped me correctly estimate page sizes and ensure that no blank pages come:

Override the two properties `IsPageCountValid` and `PageCount` as:

> ```
>     public override bool IsPageCountValid
>     {
>         get { return true; }
>     }
> ```

and

```
public override int PageCount
{
    get
    {
        if (pageCount == 0)
        {
            this.ComputePageCount();
        }
        return pageCount;
    }
}
```

Use a private function ComputePageCount to do your page size calculations (breaking your page into the exact number of pages according to a single pageSize specified).

The key to all the page count computing capabilities here setting

> `IsPageCountValid` = true

which would then always make sure the Paginator uses your overriden methods to calculate page counts.

A single page size can be specified by setting DocumentPaginator.PageSize property.

Take into account all Headers/Footers in every page. Mostly the blank/less pages are a result of wrong PageCount Calculations.